# iPhone up to date Twitter oAuth tutorial

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter

Could someone please give me a single up to date tutorial for implementing OAuth with twitter. I have gone through so many tutorials I have lost count, and not a single one of them is up to date with the new xCode. I tried the MGTTwitter, but there is no tutorial for it. On his own website, where it gives link to tutorial, it just links you to this

http://ww35.2bros1blog.com/2010/07/switching-from-basic-to-xauth-with-mgtwitterengine-on-iphone/

So no idea that that is about

I tried

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

But I dont know how to add the static folders to xCode. I tried adding the targets, but nothing to add.

Tried following

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

However, it is out of date. When I run the app, using my consumer key and secret, when I click authorise, it just closes window, then brings up authorisation window again. I enter user and pass again, does the same thing over and over again.

I downloaded latest version of sharekit, didnt really want to go down this root as all I want is the twitter authorisation and I think adding over 50 files or so is a bit much for one feature, but thought I would give it a shot. But when I open it up, comes up with error around facebook

(null): error: /Users/adam/Downloads/ShareKit-ShareKit-7a05403/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/../../../../../Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBDialog.bundle: No such file or directory

All I want is a simple authentication so users can accept and then send tweets from the app. I dont want to use the twitter framework as then users have click send twice, i.e type message into textview, then then twitter viewcontroller appears, then they click send again. I want them to be able to tweet from within the app. Yet I just cannot seem to find any tutorial that explains how to do this in detail.

Could someone please point me in the direction of a tutorial that does this, I didnt think it would be this much hassle to implement a simple authorisation into iPhone, but this is driving me insane!!!

Edit:

I got

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

This one working, however when I sign in, app crashes and the log says

```
Authenticated with user (null)
```

Anyone have any idea about that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out why I was having a problem with these twitter tools. They were using http rather than https to authenticate with Twitter which is no longer allowed. Just changed it to https and works fine